# Loading jQuery plugins after modal popup or load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am working on a project that have modal popup (I use [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)) and Ajax loads.

The problem is: everytime I call a modal or load something, my jQuery plugins (like [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) or [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)) do not work, so I have to call them all (again) with callback.

So, my question is: is there a way to do not have to open them again? A way that all plugins (or already runned functions) automatically run again, without I have to manually do this?

*If I made a mistake or my text is a little bit confuse, feel free to suggest an edit. Perhaps there are technical words to describe better my problems.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your your files using require.js.
Require have an option that is possible specify
The dependency of a file and you can also load it whenever you want without have problems like this that you are having.

Take a look in "shim" command here:

http://requirejs.org